# How to get multiple value from one sql column

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have 2 tables one is dishes and the other is ingredients. First site will display all the dishes but when a user click on the onion checkbox then the query will display items which contain onion. If user click on potato checkbox then the query will display items which contain onion AND potato and so on. it will filter down the results according to the user inputs. It would be awesome if anybody can help.

```
SELECT *
FROM (`Ingredients`)
WHERE `category` IN ('1', '8') 
AND `ingredients_name` = 'onion'
AND `ingredients_name` = 'potato'
AND `ingredients_name` = 'cream ';
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't very clear; and that query isn't going to work. What exactly are you trying to do? Can you add some examples to your question?

Comment: Tell us what you want the output of your query to contain. I don't know what multiple values from one column means. Do you mean like output three different fields for data based on one column?>

Comment: If you try to concat multiple line of one column, check GROUP_CONCAT on mysql doc.

Comment: this probably needs some sort of OR operator, although its not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hello everyone, thanks for your quick reply. 
I have 2 tables one is dishes and the other is ingredients. First  site will display all the dishes but when a user click on the onion checkbox then the query will display items which contain onion. If user click on potato checkbox then the query will display  items which contain onion AND potato and so on. it will filter down the results according to the user inputs.

Comment: @VeerajRathore Can you edit your question and post your table structures and some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select multiple values can you not use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`Ingredients`)
WHERE `category` = '1' OR  `category` = '8'
AND `ingredients_name` = 'onion'
AND `ingredients_name` = 'potato'
AND `ingredients_name` = 'cream ';
```

Comment: That won't work. You're checking `ingredients_name`, but it will only match if it has three different values. You might also want to put your OR statement in brackets, else you'll have fun with operator precedence.

Comment: @andrewsi: Yes indeed, I wasn't even looking at that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a Binary string column which contain all ingredients info for dishes
eg, 1 for onion, 10 for potato, 100 for cream ,1000 for ⋯⋯

then if you want to find all dishes contain onion, potato, cream

use this sql

select * from dishes where `meta_info` like '111%' for onion, potato, cream
use 
 select * from dishes where `meta_info` like '1_1%' for onion and cream
use 
select * from dishes where `meta_info` like '__1%' for cream

to solve it perfectly, think about lucene or sphinx

Answer (score 0):

What is the relationship between Dish and Ingredient (Many : 1, 1:1, etc)? If it is many to many something like:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM  Dish d
    JOIN DishIngredients di on di.dish_id = i.dish_id
    JOIN Ingredient i on i.ingredient_id = di.ingredient_id 
    WHERE d.`category` IN ('1', '8') 
    AND i.`ingredients_name` = 'onion'
    AND i.`ingredients_name` = 'potato'
    AND i.`ingredients_name` = 'cream ';
```

should provide the information. If it is a set number of FK, you can join on each FK to get the full constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need a separate join per ingredient, building the query dynamically.

Example:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `Dishes` a
JOIN `Ingredients` i1 ON i1.dish_id = a.id AND i1.ingredients_name = 'onion'
JOIN `Ingredients` i2 ON i2.dish_id = a.id AND i2.ingredients_name = 'potato'
JOIN `Ingredients` i3 ON i3.dish_id = a.id AND i3.ingredients_name = 'cream'
WHERE a.category IN ('1', '8');
```

I'm making several assumptions here, but you should get the idea.  Also, I would recommend using ingredient IDs, rather than strings (or, at the very least, put an index on `ingredients_name`).